# I want to display some query mongoose result data using Angular on an html page

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I have a little problem, I want to display some mongoose query result data using Angular on on an html page.

I don't know how to send data to the angular `$scope`.

app.js:

```
User.find({ Code: doc.Code}, function (err, data){
    var users = [];
    var userswithsamecode = '';
    data.forEach(function(d){
        console.log(d.nom + " " + d.prenom);
        users.push(d);
        userswithsamecode += "<li>" + d.nom +" "+ d.prenom + '</li><br>';
```

How can I send this result to the angular $scope,
collegues.html

```
<html data-ng-app="demo">
<div data-ng-controller="simple">
Name:
<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
<br/>
<ul>
<li data-ng-repeat="collegue in collegues |filter:name">{{}} </li>  
</ul>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var demo=angular.module('demo', []);
function simple($scope){
$scope.collegues=
     ];}
demo.controller('simple', simple);
</script>'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, so your first code snippet isn't complete and I don't kniw what "result" you want to send to `$scope`. Can you please add more detail? Also, how have you tried to do it? Show us what you're trying to do, don't just ask us to do it all for you.

Comment: the result wich i would display using angular is data, data represents several collections for example : {_id:..., username:jam, nom:owen, prenom:jack} and i want to display nom and prenom foreach collection with angular, to do that i tried to send data by  $http.get('/data/user/:userId/collegues').success(successCallback); but i didnt get any result, it seems very woolly how can i build the bridge between mongoose and angularjs.

Comment: Try something. Put that info (in clear English) in your question

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a model for mongo. An example

```
 var Example = mongoose.model('ExampleCollection'{
  name:String,
  description: String
  });

//posting to a mongodb
var example = new Example (
  app.post("/add-something-to-mongo", function(req, res) {
  name: req.body.name,
  description: req.body.description
  });
listing.save(function(err) {
     if(err) {
     console.log("Error! ", err);
     }else
      {
       console.log("Saved!"
      };
       });
     });
   });
```

The angular code would look something like this.

```
var app = this;
var url = "heroku_url or localhost url";
app.save = function(Example) {
// create a new object
var newExample = {
"name": $scope.name
"description": $scope.description
};
$http.post(url + "/routefromserver", newExample).success(function() {
   console.log("posting");
})
};
```

And lastly the HTML

```
<input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name" />
<input id="city" type="text" ng-model="description"/>
<button ng-click="app.save()">Save Me</button>
```